# object oriented C++ multi threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've started using some basic threading in c++0x to speed things up. For a trivial example which does nothing except test speed:

```
void my_thread_func(int n, int steps, int offset)
{
  double a[n];
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    a[i] = i + offset;
   for (int step=0; step<steps; step++)
     for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       a[i] = sin(a[i]);
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::thread> t;
   for (int i=0; i<numRuns; i++)
     t.push_back(std::thread(my_thread_func, n, steps, i));
   for (int i=0; i<numRuns; i++)
     t[i].join();
}
```

and that works quite well. My question is somewhat a general one, namely how to generalize the above idea to working with member functions. Say I have 10 Rope(s), and each rope has several (single-threaded) member functions, computeTorques(), computeForces(), etc. Assuming the Rope(s) do not share memory/resources, is there a way I can multi-thread calling each member function of each Rope without explicitly having to change the (single-threaded) code within the Rope?

Comment: It's completely dependent on the implementation of your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::bind`.

```
class Rope
{
    ...
    void compute();
};

int main()
{
   Rope ropes[10];
   std::vector<std::thread> t;

   for(auto& r : ropes)
      t.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(&Rope::compute, &r)));

   for(auto& th : t)
     th.join();
}
```

EDITED: Using lambda would be better.

```
   for(auto& r : ropes)
      t.push_back(std::thread([&]{ r.compute(); }));
```

Comment: Using std::futures and some sort of sort of thread pool would be even better.

Comment: for( auto& th : t ) th.join();

Comment: @Ethan Steinberg: futures are good when it is a particular calculated value you are interested in. That would be good if he were interested in the results of his sin() function. In the general case where the threads just do something that is not the use of a future.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `bind` nor the lambda because the `std::thread` constructor is overloaded to allow such a call directly: `std::thread(&Rope::compute, &r)`.

Comment: when I try the example, I get the following   error: unable to deduce ‘auto&&’ from 'ropes'. If I replace it with a standard for loop it works fine. Am I missing a compilation tag of some sort (other than -std=c++0x and -lrt?)   Aha. The answer seems to be the (:) notation only plays nice with vectors.

Answer (score -1):

It's completely dependent on the implementation of your object.

For some objects this would be safe, for others you could have trouble.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the syntax would go for calling a member function. Could you provide a simple example?